# missing modules error on booting

Tags: 14.04

I am getting this on `booting ubuntu`.Can someone suggest me what should be done to fix this error

```
Missing modules (cat /proc/modules ; ls /dev)

ALERT! /dev/disk/by-uuid/3333c015-4eb7-47f6-82ee-8f99d6b92e56 does not exist.
```

Comment: Please run [Boot-Repair](//help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) and [edit] your question to include a link to its resulting info log.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add there output of "sudo blkid", "cat /etc/fstab" commands.

Comment: cat: can't open '/etc/fstab' : no such file or directory